# Do I need to replace this sub floor after bad tub installation?

Tags: bathtub, subfloor, moisture

I bought this house ~6 months ago and I noticed then that the caulk around this tub was not installed properly. I just barely got around to opening it up and seeing what was underneath and I found very moist wood that breaks away very easily.[image] It looks like the sub floor is destroyed. Am I right about that? What should my next steps be?

Comment: I assume you're pulling out the tub and everything else in the area right?  That's a lot of long term moisture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it appears that you need a need new sub-flooring. Once the old tub is removed clear out all the old rotted material down to solid wood.  If necessary let the area  dry for a day or so.  Then as necessary fill voids and holes with shims and filler strips. Overlay the entire area with new quality heavy sub-flooring. Then set the new tub.

Comment: Am I going to have to replace the tub as well or can I take it out in one piece and then re-install it?

Comment: If it's an enameled steel tub, the rust on the bottom apron is probably significant.  It's probably something you will have to pull out and look at.  check the apron and where the drain connects and the lip that touches the walls.  Also price new tubs - some really are not that expensive.

Comment: I would recommend replacing the tub.  They are not that expensive.